# PairRDD, initialise variable once per key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a large `RDD[(K, V)]`. To map the values, I need a large data structure that is common to each key and is expensive to build. I cannot execute a `groupByKey` and execute a `flatMap` afterwards because the values of each key don't fit in memory. I cannot load all the structures because they don't fit in memory either. How can I execute the initialisation of the structure once per group (or the minimum number of times) and then remove it?

**Use-case**

- We have an RDD[String, String]. The key indicates the language of the value, which is a short text in that language.
- We want to categorise some tokens of the values. To do so, we need to build a trie for each language, which contains the categories of some tokens.
- Building the trie is expensive, so we cannot build it foreach (K, V) pair. A single trie will fit in memory, but keeping the tries of all languages won't (given the number of different keys).
- So, we need a way to build the trie the minimum number of times, and only keep in memory a few number of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for example use `RDD` with `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` followed by `mapPartitions`:

```scala
val partitioner: org.apache.spark.Partitioner = ???

rdd.repartitionAndSortWithinPartition(partitioner).mapPartitions { iter => {
  var currentKey: Option[String] = None
  var currentTrie: Option[Trie] = None 
  iter.map {
    case (k, v) => 
      .. // if Option(k) != currentKey update currentKey and currentTrie
      .. // Proceed with logic
  }
}}
```

or `Dataset` with `groupBy` followed by `flatMapGroups`:

```scala
rdd.toDS.groupByKey(_._1).flatMapGroups { case (key, iter) => {
  val currentTrie: Trie = ???
  iter.map { case (_, v) => ??? }
})
```

Unlike its `RDD` counterpart `Dataset` doesn't have to load all values into memory at once so size of the individual groups shouldn't be an issue.

Both solutions require full shuffle but each reference structure will be initialized only once for each key.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use-case, you can either use a broadcast variable for this large data structure

```
val broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(LargeThingy())
broadcastVar.value
```

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables

Or you can use `rdd.foreachPartition` and initialise one large thingy per partition, then process the data in the partition:

```
rdd.foreachPartition { case (data) =>
    val largeThing = LargeThing()
    data.foreach { //etc. }
}
```

Comment: I will take a look to the broadcast variables. Using the foreachPartition, how do I group values of the same key in the same partition? For the code to work, I will need that all the values of data pertain to the same key.

Comment: Given your additional info, my answer isn't going to help